# How to get the max value in relation table using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The table structure is like this:

```
Video
-------
id
source_low
source_med
source_high

Source
--------
id
duration
```

The video item can contain one or more of the source. That means, there are at least 1 source , either source_low, med, high etc.. or have all 3 source at maximum. And I would like to get the most duration between three source.

Right now I can get the value by joining the table, but how can I get the max duration for each video?

```
SELECT video
JOIN SOURCE ON video.source_low = SOURCE.id
JOIN SOURCE ON video.source_med = SOURCE.id
JOIN SOURCE ON video.source_high = SOURCE.id
```

Comment: Consider switching to (id,source,quality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single join statement (which could match multiple rows  `source` rows to a single `video`, and then use `max` to get the longest duration:

```
SELECT   v.id, MAX(duration)
FROM     video v
JOIN     source s ON s.id IN (v.source_low, v.source_med, v.source_high)
GROUP BY v.id
```